# kvm bridge dropping packets

Tags: 14.04, networking, virtualization, kvm-virtualization

Periodically one or more of the guests lose network connectivity. We are getting packet loss only in vms.

### Setup:

We're running 3 KVM guests, all Ubuntu 12.04 LTS using bridged networking.
OS on Blade : 14.04 amd64
qemu-kvm - version   2.0.0+dfsg-2ubuntu1.10 amd64 QEMU Full virtualization on x86 hardware (transitional package)

From the host:
`cat /etc/network/interfaces`:

```
auto br0
iface br0 inet static
        address x.x.x.x
        netmask 255.255.255.0
        network x.x.x.x
        broadcast x.x.x.x
        gateway x.x.x.x
        # dns-* options are implemented by the resolvconf package, if installed
        dns-nameservers x.x.x.x
        dns-search xxx.net
        bridge_ports em1
        bridge_fd 0
        bridge_stp off
        bridge_maxwait 0
```

`brctl show`:

```
bridge name     bridge id               STP enabled     interfaces
br0             8000.74e6e2803b61       no                em1
                                                                                                                                       vnet0
                                                        vnet1
virbr0          8000.000000000000       yes
```

Same is reported in old thread: https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/qemu-kvm/+bug/997978
Can you point me to some guide that can help me to resolve the issue.

Comment: did you try kernel 3.16 or more recent as mentioned in those bug reports you linked to?